# Como desabilitar a substituição de código do Eclipse para "setters"?

Tags: java, eclipse

Quando eu crio uma classe no eclipse com um atributo do tipo

```
public class MinhaClasse{
    private String variavel;
}
```

O eclipse sublinha a palavra "variavel" em amarelo e se eu clicar com o botão direito em cima, ele permite que getters e setters sejam gerados para aquela variável.

O problema é que ele também substitui referências em outros métodos do código do tipo

```
variavel = x;
```

por

```
setVariavel(x);
```

Eu sei que isso não acontece quando se usa <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> e se pede para criar *getters* e *setters* para os atributos, mas é bem menos conveniente

É possível configurar o Eclipse para não fazer essa substituição de *setters*?

ps. editado para deixar o problema mais claro

Answer (score 2):

Basta que, ao abrir a janela para definir os nomes dos métodos (isso depois de você ter clicado com o botão direito do mouse, ou <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> em cima do field - no seu exemplo `variavel`), você marcar a opção `keep field reference`

[image: SS]

Answer (score 0):

Window / Preferences -> Java / Debug

Existem 4 Checkboxes relacionados ao Hot Code Replace. Desabilitar todos eles resoverá o seu problema